# Could not load requested class : datetime

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-search

I want to use Spring with Hibernate 5. But during startup I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : datetime
```

This is my POM.xml configuration:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>               
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Full Java error stack:
https://pastebin.com/a01yU4vZ

I have in my models datetime which I want to use in MariaDB.

```
@Type(type = "datetime")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private DateType datetime;
```

I suppose that I'm missing some POM dependency for Hibernate. Can you give me some idea what dependency I have to add in order to solve the issue?

EDIT:

For datetime Hibernate configuration I use:

```
    @Column
    @Type(type = "datetime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private DateType datetime;
```

Comment: Please post the full error stack here. PasteBin is blocked for some of us.

Answer (score 0):

There is not the type of Date Time in Hibernate Date you Have:

```
Name = date  Java Type = java.sql.Date
Name = calendar_date  Java Type = java.util.Calendar
```

And if you are using Java 8

```
NAme = LocalDate  Java Type = java.time.OffsetDateTime
Name = LocalDateTimeType  Java Type = java.time.LocalDateTime
```

Check more in this [Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch03.html)

Comment: Post is updated. Please can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

For your entity field `datetime`, you should use:

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date datetime`
```

or one of the classes in the `java.time` package. In this last case you might also need to add the [following dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

In both cases I don't think the annotation `@Type(type = "datetime")` is necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still present. Looks like the issue is related to dependency of Spring?

Comment: I tried also to remove datetime from everywhere but the result is the same.

Comment: One idea: Probably exact version of Hibernate and Spring should be used?

Comment: I found the issue: it was caused because my beans were located in a remote jar which I was using as a module. Is there a way to configure Hibernate to use remote models?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about remote module